# Import an include file in react component and acess the imports

Tags: javascript, react-native, ecmascript-6, socket.io

I'm developing a react native app and have a component that looks like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './OtherImports';

class Products extends Component {

}
```

Now in another file called OtherImports.js i want to import other dependencies/modules so that i can reuse them in all my components.

In OtherImports.js

```
window.navigator.userAgent = 'react-native';
import io from 'socket.io-client/dist/socket.io';
```

Now when I include(import) this file in my component, I get an error.

How can I include this file in react components and yet be able to use them? for instance the variable **io** in my example

Comment: you should include the error message, what error you are getting?

Comment: @mamounothman on the Products component it tells that 'Cant find variable io'

Comment: check if you change it to this `let io = require('socket.io-client/socket.io');` would it work?

Comment: @mamounothman No it didn't work. It keeps giving me the same error ie "Can't find the variable: io"

Comment: Ok add this line to your `OtherImports.js`, `export default io;`

Comment: @mamounothman this now works

Comment: Ok I will add it as answer and I will add few comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do (based on the comments) you are trying to import `socket.io` using custom file import here what you have to add to your file to make it work:

`OtherImports.js`

```
window.navigator.userAgent = 'react-native';
import io from 'socket.io-client/dist/socket.io';
export io;
```

and you can use `export default`

**Note**: what you could have done is to import it directly in your code where you are using it.

Comment: Based on your **Note** above, I wanted to use the 'socket' in different and many components/files. So i felt that it would be easy to just import a single line rather than having to paste those in each file @mamoun